# boost::optional alternative in C++ Standard Library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std, boost-optional

I'm trying to get my program working without `boost` usage, but can't find an alternative of some useful patterns. Namely, I can't find `boost::optional`-likewise pattern in the standard library. Is there some standard alternative for `boost::optional` (C++11 or somewhere else)?

Comment: C++0x == C++11, removed from question. :)

Comment: You can use a nullable pointer as a cheap and unsafe alternative to `boost::optional`. Or maybe `std::unique_ptr`, where the value 0 (null_ptr, NULL) is interpreted an uninitialized optional type. Besides the drawbacks the good thing is that you dont need to implement anything; but just keep the abstraction in mind. A clue about this is given in the boost manual itself http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/development.html#boost_optional.development.the_interface "As a result, you might be able to replace optional<T> by T* on some situations but not always"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Roll your own according to the boost spec. The documentation is quite exhaustive and the code isn't that complex, but this still requires above average C++ skills.

To update this answer: C++14 unfortunately did not ship with `std::optional`. The current proposal (Revision 5) is [N3793](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html) and it is expected to be shipped as a separate technical specification or to become part of C++17.

Comment: In some environments, it is politically impossible to use boost, sadly.

Comment: Have you thought about [extracting just optional from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: Good answer, except for the ", but why would you try to get rid of boost anyway?" - Like others have posted, Boost isn't always feasible; not to mention, including such a massive library (and all the headaches of managing version dependencies) for one very light-weight feature is not ideal.

Comment: @Copperpot There you go. I actually removed that piece of opinion.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend avoiding boost::optional. This is primarily because operator= assigns the stored object instead of destroying and copy/move constructing. It seems like a cool feature because it looks like it logically means the right thing but that's only true for an lvalue, not an xvalue - which is what is held by boost optional. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage makes it very easy to roll your own that behaves correctly (it's just five or six lines)

Comment: @codeshot I'm a little confused here, shouldn't the stored object's type have a suitable operator= defined for it that knows what to do in each case?

Comment: You can't have operator= on a constant object or a reference. So you can't even express such a program. The operator= of the instance of optional *itself* would need to be specialised for when there can be no correct operator= following sensible laws so that it remakes the stored object entirely. That might be confusing to some but okay for others. unfortunately N3793 section X.Y.4.3 has operator=(nullopt_t) which will be a problem for optional<optional<T>> - which is an important use case for implementing formally defined programs but those always need to compose sensibly

Comment: Update: [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is part of C++17.

Comment: @pmr, please, update your question to include C++17.

Answer (score 12):

There is currently [a proposal for C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html) (or C++17). So the answer is (probably) not yet :).

Comment: Apparently it has just been voted out C++14 into a Technical Specification (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) :(

Comment: Isn't it the case that 'voting out' in C++ committee-speak actually means 'voting for' ?

Answer (score 1):

Like [pmr explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870497/369009), it is not possible right now, and will not be until C++17 is out.

However, you should be able to use this [single header library](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) on github as a drop in replacement of boost- or std optional. It has no dependencies (except a c++11/c++14 capable compiler).