# Does Qt have its own boost::optional alternative?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Does Qt have its own boost::optional alternative, or should I just use boost::optional?

Answer (score 8):

Qt has a 'variant' type, but not an 'optional' type.  I think that `boost::optional` (or, in newer C++ versions, `std::optional`) is a reasonable choice.

Comment: As an addendum, programmers prefer Qt types over the stdlib alternatives (for example, QVariant vs std::variant, QVector vs std::vector, etc) due to the Qt functions doing processing with them natively, obviating conversions. However due to the nonexistence of a Qt optional type, it's perfectly reasonable to use std::optional.

Comment: what do you mean "programmers prefer". I find it pretty annoying that Qt decided to recreate so many basic types on their own, instead of sticking to creating functionalities that are not part of the standard.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like `QVariant` already can do what `boost::optional` was intended to do. You have:

```
bool QVariant::isNull() const
bool QVariant::isValid() const
Type QVariant::type() 
static QVariant QVariant::fromValue(const T & value)
T QVariant::value()
```

So you can wrap any type, check if the variant is null or valid or even get the type to use with an if or switch statement.

Comment: Sure but QVariant is an overkill. It has more overhead and hides type of its contents.

Comment: If one already uses Qt it is a viable option, I doubt it will end up used in places where its memory or performance overheads will be exacerbated.

Comment: QVariant isn't a good fit for the use case of optionals. From the docos for QVariant:     Null variants is not a single state and two null variants may easily return false on the == operator if they do not contain similar null values.

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 there was introduced std::optional: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

I think it's more usefull in Qt project, than boost one. There is still no any QOptional class in Qt.

Answer (score 2):

There is [qt-maybe template](https://github.com/robertknight/qt-maybe)  implemented on top of Qt's QVariant container, but it's not in "standard" qt lib.

Answer (score 1):

**No** there is no alternative for boost::optional at present. You can also refer this thread: [boost::optional alternative in C++ Standard Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870205/boostoptional-alternative-in-c-standard-library)